# VBA Compile Error 'Wend Without While'

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA macro in excel that has run fine for a while. I've been making changes with these loops already working and suddenly the code is not compiling:

> Compile error: Wend without While

I have tried changing to Do While...Loop loops, but I got the equivalent

> Compile error: Loop without Do

Here is the structure of my code:

```
'This loop is fine
While '(code for evaluation)
'code to run in loop
Wend

While '(more eval code)
'code
  While '(eval code)
  'code
  Wend '<--This is where the compile error occurs
  'code
  While '(eval code)
  'code
  Wend
'code
Wend
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be the issue? (Bonus: Does the indentation of code actually matter?)

Comment: The problem is **usually** caused by an **IF** without an equivalent **END IF** somewhere in the code.

Comment: I suspect you're actually missing a closing statement for a block in the code you left out. For indentation, res ipsa loquitur. ;)

Comment: @Gary'sStudent That was it! I don't think this question is a duplicate (I couldn't find one) so please post an answer!

Comment: _Does the indentation of code actually matter?_ - No for the compiler. Yes for programmers.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Yes, you are absolutely right sir. This is sadly funny

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This message **Wend without While** usually indicates an un-terminated **IF**

Somewhere there may be an **IF** without the matching **End If**

*(This kind of error message is a bit annoying since it hides the true error)*

Answer (score 2):

The real problem is that you have a method that does too many things.

You can locate the mismatched code block, and fix it - but you'd be dismissing a readability issue with an "hey it works, leave it alone" excuse.

```
While
'code to run in loop
Wend

' **** move to another method
While 
'code

' **** move to another method
  While 
  'code
  Wend 

' **** move to another method
  'code
  While 
  'code
  Wend

'code
Wend
```

Extracting methods in VBA code can be a bit of a pain, because parameters and return values must be determined, and then the extraction point needs to be turned into a method/function call. Fortunately, [there's a tool for that](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/wiki/Features#refactorings) (disclaimer: I wrote it).

Comment: This is a good suggestion, but it does seem a bit obsessive to convert that first block you marked to another method. Also quick question: might there be any loss any speed using function extraction if my macro is going through a lot of files and through each loop many times?

Comment: Nothing significant, no. Readability over micro-optimizations-for-performance! (I *am* a bit obsessed with readability though ;) ..extracting that first block or not, depends on what the `'code` comment actually stands for