# Compile Error using while and when

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently experiencing an issue with the While and Wend statement But first let me give a little background context to explain what it is that I am trying to accomplish.
I have a button which I click and creates a new sheet with the name of a person and using autofilter copies entire row relevant to them (where their name is present) from a source table. That works without any issues and using the code below ( Which many of you might recognize from Ron Bruin) I manage to send the information with the click of a button to all the people I have added with a similar code (somewhat like the generic one I included below) however that presented a bit of a problem.
Lets say there are a total of 30 people and both the number of people and names are a constant. If all the names appear as a worksheet then I am able to send without any issues whatsoever. The problem is that this is run monthly and on some months not all of those 30 people will be on the sheet. Taking the example below this would mean that if John Doe and Jane Doe both had a sheet with Data in it I would be able to send however If Jane did not appear in the source table then the code would break. I realized then I would need some sort of If statement and after multiple attempts I could not get to work. Then I discovered the While/Wend statement which seems to be the better option to use for this purpose. Logically speaking what I am trying to accomplish below is that "While there is a sheet called John Doe" then carry out all the code below it, if the condition is not Met then resume executing after the Wend". Currently I think I have one and potentially 2 issues here:

The first is that when executing the code I get an error "Compile Error: Wend without While".

According to the answer [VBA Compile Error 'Wend Without While'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29014366/vba-compile-error-wend-without-while) it seems to be related to unterminated IF statements but that does not seem to be the case

The Second is that due to that I cannot test whether 
          **While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name <> "John Doe")** is a valid while statement that will work as I intend it to do so.

I would appreciate if someone could explain why this is not working so that I can learn from it. Thank you for taking the time to read through this post! If additional information is required or something I wrote is not clear please let me know.

```
Sub emailfitest()

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim rng As Range
Dim strbody As String

On Error Resume Next

While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name <> "John Doe")

Set rng = Sheets("John Doe").Range("A1:K80").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error Resume Next




Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail

    .SentonBehalfofName = "bla@domain.com"
    .To = "blabla@domain.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "Bla bla 123"
    .WrapText = True

    .HtmlBody = "<HTML><BODY><p> " & strTo & " <br /> " & strCC & " <br /> </p>" & _
    "<p>Hi Bla,  " & " </B>  <br /> <br /< </p>" & _
    "<p>text1<br /> <br /> </p> " & _
    "<p>text2.<br /> </p> " & _
    "<li>bulletpoint 1<br /> </li> " & _
    "<li>bulletpoint2<br /> <br /> </li> " & _
    "<p>text3<br /> </p> " & _
    "<p> text4 <A href=https://blabbla.com>Here</A><br /></p>" & _
    "<p>text5</p> <br /> <br />" & _
    "<p>text6 <br /></p>" & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send

   Wend
   End With


On Error GoTo 0

     With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing




While (Worksheets("Jane Doe").Name <> "Jane Doe")
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Set rng = Sheets("Jane Doe").Range("A1:K80").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

On Error Resume Next




Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail

    .SentonBehalfofName = "blabla@domain.com"
    .To = "thingsandstuff@domain.com"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "hello1233h12"
    .WrapText = True

    .HtmlBody = "<HTML><BODY><p> " & strTo & " <br /> " & strCC & " <br /> </p>" & _
    "<p>Hi Jane" & " </B>  <br /> <br /< </p>" & _
    "<p>text1<br /> <br /> </p> " & _
    "<p>text2<br /> </p> " & _
    "<li>bulletpoint1<br /> </li> " & _
    "<li>bulletpoint2<br /> <br /> </li> " & _
    "<p>text3<br /> </p> " & _
    "<p>blablabla  <A href=https://bblablabsa.com >Here</A><br /></p>" & _
    "<p>text4</p> <br /> <br />" & _
    "<p>text5<br /></p>" & RangetoHTML(rng)
    .Send

Wend

End With

On Error GoTo 0

     With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub

   --------------------------------------------
Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2013
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With

'Publish the sheet to a htm file
 With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With

'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.readall
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

'Close TempWB
TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

'Delete the htm file we used in this function
Kill TempFile

Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Swap your `End With` and `Wend` statements over. You need to close the clauses in the reverse order you opened them.

Comment: BTW: and you really should try to understand your own code. For example I count 6 times On Error Resume Next (to use that is a bad idea at all) in your code. This shows to me that you use a lot of copy + paste. But you need to know what you really do there. It would also be helpful to structure the code better.

Comment: Besides the End with and Wend statements, I'm not sure your code will run..
While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name <> "John Doe"), how is this going to work ?
Maybe I just don't understand it..

Comment: @Rory, thanks that sorted out the issue!

Comment: @cboden: I copied this module in a bit of a hurry but i have a clean backup elsewhere. I also avoided using the on error go to label x ( as a means to solve this particular problem I have presented. But in any case my VBA skills are basically copying and pasting from different sources and try and get something to work by trial and error and some google searches. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: @Alex4336  Rory and Macro Man pointed out the mistakes which caused the code to break but now the second part of the problem remains. Because the while statement gets an error stating Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range when there is a case that the sheet name does not exist. The while condition i am looking for should be something like " While there is a sheet named person A then carry out the next part of the code (until Wend)

Comment: @Alex4336 setting it as While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name <> "") gets the code running. Now on the final challenge it is in a perpetual loop when executing thus sending countless e-mails. Lets see if i can figure this one out

Comment: I'd make a WorksheetExists Function to return a Boolean value, if there is a worksheet with the desired name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `End With` and `Wend` are the wrong way around.

```
While (Worksheets("Jane Doe").Name <> "Jane Doe")
...
    With OutMail
    ...
    ...
    End With '// <~~ Close the With block first.
Wend '// <~~ THEN close the While block
```

---

You're also missing an `End With` on this block:

```
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
```

Which means you can't use `With OutMail` on the second run because you're still inside the first `With` block.

All `With` statements must be completed with an `End With` at the end of the block.

Comment: Hi Macro Man, Your suggestions worked and thanks for the explanation! Now the only problem is the second with the While statement because the code breaks when there is a sheet that does not exist with the given name. I have tried switching it to something like While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name = True) but it also doesnt work

Comment: Switched this ---> While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name = True) to this While (Worksheets("John Doe").Name <> and now atleast the code runs although it gets stuck in loop. Going to see if i can figure out that part of the problem since otherwise it starts sends emails continuously.

Comment: That condition is always going to be true - so the loop will never end, what are you actually trying to test there? When should that loop end?

Comment: Hi. Basically what I want it to do is to use the While statement to verify that  sheet John Doe exists and in that event send an email with the specified range and the text to the destination. If however there is no sheet with John Doe found then it should skip right to Jane Doe where another While statement would validate if sheet Jane Doe exists if not skip to the next person and so on until end sub. The people it needs to check for an existing sheet is the same each month bt on any given month 1 of those persons may not have a sheet and as such that person should not receive an email.